# Pending BTC transaction for more than 30 hours

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoin-wallet-app

I have made a transaction 0.0387621 BTC yesterday, its been more than 30 hrs, the transaction is still in pending status.

I have put the right address and BTC value (excluding the token charges).

Kindly let me know any solutions that can resolve it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the transaction ID? How much did you pay in fee?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this: [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

It would seem you did not attach enough of the fee. How many sat/byte does your transaction show?